# App crash on start in other device Binary XML Error - ANDROID

Tags: android, xml

I made an Application, and I debugged it on my Samsung android 7.0 API 26 and it works well, but as long as a started testing it on another device, it crashes at the start and it gives me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.auvray.tasky, PID: 11649
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.auvray.tasky/com.auvray.tasky.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                  at com.auvray.tasky.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:32)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_person_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020070
                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2136)
                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:861)
                                                                  at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:62)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:58)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                  at com.auvray.tasky.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:32) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                               Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                                                                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2132)
                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:861) 
                                                                  at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:62) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:58) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                  at com.auvray.tasky.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:32) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know what is happening because it works well on my Samsung but as long as I try on my LG it crashes, I see the error that it's causing by my login XML file but there is no error on it:

**activity_login.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/login_background"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_backg" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_login_ed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass_login_ed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_https_black_24dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_https_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_login_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/LOGINN"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forg_pass_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/forgot"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offline_login_TV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/offline"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noaccTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/noaccount"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signupTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/signup"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there anyone who can tell me what the error is and why it crashes on another device while it works on mine? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which gradle version you are using? See in the file named **gradle-wrapper.properties**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are using a vector drawable in an unsupported way. Since the error you posted indicates that the system is having trouble inflating an `EditText`, I can only assume that `@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp` is a vector drawable.

The reason you can use vectors inside `ImageView` is that you're using the `app:srcCompat` attribute, which is actually an attribute of `AppCompatImageView`. For `TextView` and its subclasses (e.g. `EditText` and `Button`), the `android:drawableLeft` (and top/right/bottom) attributes do not support vector drawables.

The easiest solution would be to replace your vector drawable with a .png file. You could also modify your layout to include an `ImageView` next to your `EditText` so that you can use the `app:srcCompat` attribute.